# Deprecated Classes and Methods in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

Using a module from Magento 2.2 to Magento 2.3, I notice the code has several deprecated Magento Core Classes and Methods.
For example, the Registry (\Magento\Framework\Registry).

Is there any guide/article which says which classes and methods we should use instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can find solution here in below link.

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/

Comment: @DominicXigen, Yes in that article there is reason available why some Methods are now deprecated in Registry class and alternatives for Registry class available.